# SQL - Need a solution of additional unique identifier column based on two integer columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, uniqueidentifier

When I JOIN two tables in a SELECT statement, I get some duplicates in column 1 in the result set, like so:

```
|     ID1 |     ID2 |
|      12 |      34 |
|      12 |       4 |
|     123 |       1 |
|     123 |       4 |
```

But the combination of ID1, ID2 would always be unique in my result set.

I need to have a *separate column* that would uniquely identify the entire result set, in a way that each combination of ID1, ID2 would produce the same new identifier, no matter when I perform the select. I am not allowed to use a temporary tables, and obviously tricks like **ROW_NUMBER ()** over the result set wouldn't work either, because they may produce different identifiers for the same combination of ID1, ID2 after some of the two tables gets updated.

I tried the technique of concatenating the two integers from the select statements into one integer, like so:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2,
CAST(CONCAT(CAST(ID1 AS nvarchar(100)), CAST(ID2 AS nvarchar(100))) AS INT) AS Identifier
```

but it does not solve the problem either, because now different combinations may get the same identifier:

```
'12' + '34' = '1234'
'123' + '4' = '1234'
```

I need to have something like:

```
|     ID1 |     ID2 | Identifier |
|      12 |      34 |          1 |
|      12 |       4 |          2 |
|     123 |       1 |          3 |
|     123 |       4 |          4 |
```

And when one of the tables gets a new row that corresponds to ID = 12 from the other table, the previously defined identifiers will remain the same, like so:

```
|     ID1 |     ID2 | Identifier |
|      12 |      34 |          1 |
|      12 |       4 |          2 |
|      12 |       2 |        578 |
|     123 |       1 |          3 |
|     123 |       4 |          4 |
```

That is, each combination of integers ID1, ID2 would produce the same new identifier, no matter when I perform the SELECT statement. How would I create that Identifier column to satisfy my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know in advance the maximum value of these integers, then you could use arithmetics.

Say that they range from 0 to 999, then:

```
id1 * 1000 + id2 as identifier
```

Comment: Will that guarantee that any id1, id2 will get different identifier?

Comment: @B.Sverediuk: as long as both `id1` and `id2` are smaller than `1000`: yes. If they have another  range of values, you need to adapt the multiplier. Say values range from `0` to `99999`, then use `100000`, and so on.

Comment: Along that same line, you could also use the first column as a whole number and add to it the result of (id2 / 1000). Obviously a numeric datatype would be needed.

Comment: And to round this out, you could format your "numbers" with zero-filling and then concatenate as strings. E.g., (12, 34) would become 00120034 while (1, 234) becomes 00010234

Comment: Yes, I see it works. I can't use id1 * 100000 + id2 because it may result in integer overflow, so I used id1 * 10000 + id2, because id2 will not exceed 9999. Thank you.